# Need help on finding a good gaming laptop, within my budget range

Tags: laptop

So my four year Samsung computer couldn't run games really well such as those MMORPG games running with 10-20 fps, and well optimized game with around 50 fps. I really started to wanting to buy a better computer specifically for gaming when I didn't even have the minimum requirement of specs to play, Overwatch.

I'd like a laptop that can run different genres of games for about 60 fps and under hopefully. My budget range for this laptop is around $500.

So here's the specifications of my gaming laptop

- Able to run most recent, and old games. At 60 fps, or less.
- Laptop, I don't really want desktop because it not portable.
- Preferably last for about 3-4 years until I need a new one to meet the standard requirement for 3-4 years later.

Lastly please link to me what you find within my price range, and specifications.

Comment: How about a portable desktop? Gaming laptops are barely portable themselves and represent, in general, one of the worst investments in computer technology due to the form factor not being able to cope with the energy, heat dissipation, and size requirements generally needed for good gaming - for example, you can outperform a $300 laptop CPU with a $70 desktop part. That's the level of inefficiency we are dealing with here.

Comment: @AdamWykes I am really confused on what you mean a portable desktop? Do you mean building a laptop?

Comment: I mean a desktop that is very small, possibly with a handle, which can connect to any nearby screen and use a small wireless keyboard and mouse set for control.

Thanks for the help ArtofCode, on converting this to a comment, which it was indeed meant to be. The mobile app is unforgiving to clumsy fingers such as mine.

Comment: I agree with Adam. Besides, your price range for your intended usage is quite low. You didn't specify: full HD or not? For 500€ on a fullHD, do not expect running "most games" at 60fps. However, if you stand with a 1366x768 screen, you may find what you are looking for (I'm talking about laptops here)

Comment: Would you be willing to go used? Last-gen gaming laptops tend to be much cheaper.